# The data written exceeds the ttl time limit and the data is not deleted

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

The data written exceeds the ttl time limit and the data is not deleted.

When I was testing version 2.4, I created a DB and set the TTL to one minute. Then I created a table and added some data. Why does it not expire and be automatically deleted?

It doesn't seem to be a time zone problem. It's the same when I change the time zone. It's because the open source version doesn't support it, or I'm using it wrong. I want to make a function that only stores the data of the last three months, and it will be automatically deleted when it expires.Anyone who is free can help guide me?